# The toggle/hamburger icon is not displaying anything on small devices when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm encountering an issue with my website's navigation menu. When I click on the hamburger icon on smaller devices, the expected links do not appear as I anticipated. I've thoroughly reviewed my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of this problem.

To provide some context, I have a toggle button with the class "toggle-button" that displays three span elements to create the hamburger icon. The navigation menu is enclosed within a "nav-menu" div and contains several navigation items like Home, About Me, Timeline, My Blogs, and Contact Me.

```js
const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
const navMenu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');
const closeIcon = document.querySelector('.close-button');

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleButton.classList.toggle('active');
  navMenu.classList.toggle('active');

  if (toggleButton.classList.contains('active')) {
    const buttonRect = toggleButton.getBoundingClientRect();
    navMenu.style.top = buttonRect.top + buttonRect.height + 'px';
    navMenu.style.left = buttonRect.left + 'px';
  }
});

closeIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleButton.classList.remove('active');
  navMenu.classList.remove('active');
  toggleButton.innerHTML = '<span></span><span></span><span></span>';
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!navMenu.contains(event.target) && event.target !== toggleButton && navMenu.classList.contains('active')) {
    navMenu.classList.remove('active');
    toggleButton.classList.remove('active');
    toggleButton.innerHTML = '<span></span><span></span><span></span>';
  }
});

const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

navLinks.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const target = link.getAttribute("data-id");

    navLinks.forEach(function(navLink) {
      navLink.classList.remove("active-btn");
    });
    link.classList.add("active-btn");

    const section = document.getElementById(target);
    if (section) {
      section.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }

    if (window.innerWidth <= 767) {
      navMenu.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle-button {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-button span {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 6px auto;
  background-color: #008000;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .toggle-button.active span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  }
  .toggle-button.active span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .toggle-button.active span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  }
  .toggle-button.active+.nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  .nav-container {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
  }
  .nav-item {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  .close-button {
    display: none;
  }
  .close-button span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .toggle-button.active~.close-button {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 1rem;
    z-index: 1000;
  }
  .toggle-button.active~.close-button span:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .toggle-button.active~.close-button span:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .toggle-button.active~.close-button span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .toggle-button.active~.nav-menu .nav-link {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .navigation.active {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .navigation.active .nav-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  .nav-item {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-button" id="toggleBtn">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<nav class="navigation">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/70" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div class="theme-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-menu">
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="home.html" class="nav-link active-btn" data-id="home">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="about.html" class="nav-link" data-id="about">About Me</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="timeline.html" class="nav-link" data-id="timeline">Timeline</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="blog.html" class="nav-link" data-id="blog">My Blogs</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-item">
        <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link" data-id="contact">Contact Me</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you see the error in the console?

Comment: Not the fix, but did you notice that your css @media only screen are both set to almost the same max-width?

Comment: `.close-button` doesn't exist.